# Reuse a Jquery Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to reuse a function i made, but with any help yet.

Here is my index.html.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JqueryScript.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    //MYLIBRARY.init(['#button1']);
    execute(['#button1']);
    execute(['#button2']);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" id="button1">Click Me!</button>
<button type="button" id="button2">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my script.

```
function execute (Args){
    _args = Args;
    $(function() {
        $(_args[0]).click(function() {
          alert("hello " + _args[0]);
          return false;
        });
    });
}
```

The problem is always triggers the second alert windows (#button2). How can i make it work with both alert windows?

Comment: What do you mean reuse? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you have a problem, if yes, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are wondering why both buttons alert the same output.

Because `_args` is **global**. Thus the second invokation will overwrite `_args`.

Use `var` to make it local:

```
var _args = Args;
```

Your code could still be improved ([see @Town's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701511/reuse-a-jquery-script/6701560#6701560)), but this should get you started.

---

You also have errors in your HTML

```
<script src="jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--                         ^^                              -->
<script src="JqueryScript.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--                         ^^                              -->
```

Comment: +1 Felix, I was just preparing a demo of that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/e78Aa/) :)

Comment: Thank you guys!. It was as simple as that :)!

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are you trying to do?

From what I can see, you could achieve the same functionality as what you have with simply:

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        alert("hello #" + this.id);
    });
});
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/T9EzA/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like C to me :)

You'd be better off with

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function () {
   execute('#button1');
   execute('#button2');
}

function execute(buttonId)
{
    $(buttonId).click(function () { alert('Hello ' + this.id); });

}

</script>
```

Comment: `this.attr('id')` will not work. Inside the click handler, `this` refers to the DOM element, but `attr` is a jQuery method.

Comment: You can simply use `this.id` (see my answer) or, if you really love jQuery so much that you want to use it even when it's not necessary: `$(this).attr('id')`.

Comment: I do love jQuery that much! I want to kiss it! But fair enough, I didn't test my code and I thought `this` was a jQuery object in that context. Fixed now.